# What is the correct reaction mechanism for the following :

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrocarbons, carbene

**The question is :**

[image]

Now, this is what I have done :

[image]

So I dont know how to proceed to the final product. In some book they tell we need to break the cyclopropane to get the desirable answer but how ?

Please help.

Answer (score 4):

This [paper](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/1975/p1/p19750001638/unauth) (JCS Perkin 1 (1975) 1638-40) reports that dichlorocarbene reacts with cyclopentadiene at 180C to give chlorobenzene. The strained cyclopropyl ring opens to give insertion with loss of chloride anion.  I see no reason why dibromocarbene should give a different outcome, so the answer is C.

See this SE answer [How does chloroform react with cyclopentadiene in base?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/97812/how-does-chloroform-react-with-cyclopentadiene-in-base)

Answer (score -2):

Here OTs being a good leaving group will be eliminated by alc KOH making cyclopent-1,3-diene, t-BuO- being a solvent will make :CBr2 which will act as a Base and abstract proton from C5. Hence option D will be the answer.

Comment: Do you have a literature reference for this?